# getting value from the database column

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, android-cursor

I am trying to get the value of column threadid where id(which is unique) is equal to the id I am sending to the getthreadid function.threadid contains the values in data type long, But I don't know why my app crashes in doing this,Please help,Thanks in advance.

```
long id;
long threadid = datasource.getthreadid(id);
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.valueOf(threadid), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

public long getthreadid(long id)
{
    String ide = String.valueOf(id);
    String queryz = "SELECT " + "," + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_THREADID 
        + " FROM " + MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME 
        + " WHERE " + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + "=" + ide;
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(queryz, null);
    long threadid = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("threadid"));
    return threadid;
}
```

My database create query is:

```
static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "+"message"+
            "( " +"id"+" integer primary key autoincrement,"+ "threadid long,parentid integer,message  text not null,messagestatus text); ";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your query is **wrong**

```
 String queryz = "SELECT " + "," + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_THREADID 
        + " FROM " + MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME 
        + " WHERE " + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + "=" + ide;
```

Expected Output "SELECT , COLUMN FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMNID = VALUE "
A **WRONG QUERY**

Should be this

```
  String queryz = "SELECT " + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_THREADID 
            + " FROM " + MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME 
            + " WHERE " + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + "=" + ide;
```

Expected Output "SELECT COLUMN FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMNID = VALUE "

Check for your **database!=null** and then **database.isOpen()** and if executes the

check your **cursor!= null** and then **cursor.getCount() > 0**

Comment: query structure like select , columnName from TableName where columnID = value

Comment: yeah u were right i did'nt notice ,but still its not working, check my database create query too in my edit question ..

Comment: @Talib check if database != null and isOpen

Comment: test about everything but failed :/

Comment: @Talib then put your logcat

Comment: thanks its done I forgot to call cursor.movetofirst() , edit your answer so i can mark,Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Talib added all condition which you must follow at every query for fetching record otherwise even for no return cursor.moveToFirst() throw error